# Get back the same result when trying to find different data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date, postgresql-8.4

I can get the `15/02` - `21/06` date range data on every year from the query below.

```
SELECT * FROM dim_date
WHERE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM date_cal) BETWEEN 3 AND 5
 OR (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM date_cal) = 2 AND EXTRACT (DAY FROM date_cal) >= 15)
 OR (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM date_cal) = 6 AND EXTRACT (DAY FROM date_cal) <= 21)
```

But the problem is, when i want to find from year `2010 - 2012`, I get back the same result.

Range that i want to get:

```
2010-02-15 - 2010-06-15
2011-02-15 - 2011-06-15
2012-02-15 - 2012-06-15

SELECT * FROM dim_date
WHERE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM date_cal) BETWEEN 3 AND 5
 OR (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM date_cal) = 2 AND EXTRACT (DAY FROM date_cal) >= 15)
 OR (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM date_cal) = 6 AND EXTRACT (DAY FROM date_cal) <= 21)
AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM date_cal) BETWEEN 2010 AND 2012
```

Who can help me about this!

Comment: Consider the [follow-up question with more answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11944762/939860). And [this related question with much more on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169410/how-do-you-do-date-math-that-ignores-the-year/15179731).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is a lack of brackets: In SQL `AND` takes precedence over `OR`, so you need to put brackets around your whole previous expression:

```
SELECT * FROM dim_date
WHERE ( -- added bracket
 EXTRACT (MONTH FROM date_cal) BETWEEN 3 AND 5
 OR (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM date_cal) = 2 AND EXTRACT (DAY FROM date_cal) >= 15)
 OR (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM date_cal) = 6 AND EXTRACT (DAY FROM date_cal) <= 21)
 ) -- added bracket
AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM date_cal) BETWEEN 2010 AND 2012
```

Without the brackets, you get `A or B or (C and D)`, but you want `(A or B or C) and D`