# Aggregate functions on multiple joined tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, aggregate-functions, cross-join

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE foo_bar (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    foo_id bigint NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tag (
    name text NOT NULL,
    target_id bigint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, target_id)
);
```

I'm trying to create a view such that I get all of the fields of table `foo`, the count of items in `foo_bar` where `foo.id = foo_bar.foo_id`, and a text array of all tags where `foo.id = tag.target_id`.  If we have:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 'one');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2, 'two');
INSERT INTO foo_bar VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO foo_bar VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO foo_bar VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO foo_bar VALUES (4, 1);
INSERT INTO foo_bar VALUES (5, 2);
INSERT INTO tag VALUES ('a', 1);
INSERT INTO tag VALUES ('b', 1);
INSERT INTO tag VALUES ('c', 2);
```

The result should return:

```
foo.id    | foo.name     | count       | array_agg
--------------------------------------------------
1         | one          | 3           | {a, b}
2         | two          | 2           | {c}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.id, f.name, COUNT(b.id), array_agg(t.name)
FROM foo AS f, foo_bar AS b, tag AS t
WHERE f.id = t.target_id AND f.id = b.foo_id
GROUP BY f.id, b.id;
```

These are the results I'm getting (note the `count` is incorrect):

```
foo.id    | foo.name     | count       | array_agg
--------------------------------------------------
1         | one          | 2           | {a, b}
2         | two          | 1           | {c}
```

The `count` is always the count of tags instead of the count of distinct `foo_bar` values.  I've tried reordering/modifying the `GROUP BY` and the `SELECT` clauses which returns different results but not the ones that I'm looking for.  I think I'm having trouble with the `array_agg()` function, but I'm not sure if that's the case or how to resolve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT f.id, f.name, b.fb_ct, t.tag_names
FROM   foo f
LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT foo_id AS id, count(*) AS fb_ct
    FROM   foo_bar
    GROUP  BY 1
    ) b USING (id)
LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT target_id AS id, array_agg(name) AS tag_names
    FROM   tag
    GROUP  BY 1
    ) t USING (id)
ORDER  BY f.id;
```

Produces the desired result.

- Rewrite with explicit `JOIN` syntax. Makes it so much easier to read and understand (and debug).
- By joining to multiple `1:n` related tables, rows would multiply each other producing a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) - which is very expensive nonsense. It's an unintended `CROSS JOIN` by proxy. Related:

  - [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)
- To avoid this, join at most *one* `n`-table to the `1`-table before you aggregate (`GROUP BY`). You could aggregate two times, but it's cleaner and faster to aggregate `n`-tables separately *before* joining them to the `1`-table.
- As opposed to your original (with implicit `INNER JOIN`). I use **`LEFT JOIN`** to avoid losing rows from `foo` that have no matching row in `foo_bar` or `tag`.
- Once the unintended `CROSS JOIN` is removed from the query, there is no need for adding `DISTINCT` any more - assuming that `foo.id` is unique.

Comment: @Bill: This should be very fast even for a million rows. But why guess if you can just test? Populate your tables with 100k rows and run the query with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. You can find an example [how to build a a test with `generate_series()` easily here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169410/how-do-you-do-date-math-that-ignores-the-year/15179731#15179731). There are many more on SO. Also consider the added bit of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the ballpark, that's what I was interested in. I will definitely test but don't have production hardware available at the moment and testing in my VM wouldn't produce useful results. I just needed to know if this was an obviously horrible idea that I should correct immediately. Thanks again!