# How can I get results from a JPA entity ordered by distance?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, plpgsql

I am currently writing a mobile application where the user has to pick a location from a list. All the locations are stored in a Postgres database using JPA from a Play app.

What I would like to do is get the users location in the app, and then make a request to get the first 20 or 50 locations nearest to that user.

If I was using my own data structure for this, I would use a KD-Tree. However, I am very new to JPA/Play/PostgreSQL so I am unsure how to handle data persistance manually.

The only thing I can think of with my current knowledge would be to look at each location and determine it's distance but that would be incredibly slow on such a huge database.

Is there a query I can run to say "give me the X first results ordered by distance from this latitude and longitude?

EDIT: I am using Heroku and since the application is in the early stages of development, I would prefer to not have to pay the $200/month Heroku requires if you want to use PostGIS with your app.

Comment: I assume the search-radius does not have to be exact? An approximation is good enough?

Comment: An approximation is definitely good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *really* don't want to be rolling your own data structure for this, but fortunately you're using PostgreSQL, so you're in luck. Use [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/). It's going to be orders of magnitude faster than anything you can build in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Unfortunately, the cheapest plan with Heroku that lets you use PostGIS is $200 a month which I can't afford. Do you know of any other options?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no. Heroku sits on top of AWS, so you could cut out the middleman and go straight to Amazon, but of course that costs you time (instead of money).

Comment: @eliot: There *is* a way with standard PostgreSQL. But you need to know your plpgsql ...

Comment: @eliot There are also dedicated PostGIS hosting services, but a good option can be to get a server from someone like Hetzner (http://www.hetzner.de/en/), Linode (http://linode.com), etc and just run Pg on that, then you can install whatever you want. Also, when "in the early stages of development" you can and probably should just run it on your local PC.

Answer (score 3):

This is a largely simplified version of a function I use in an app that built around 3 years ago. Adapted to the question at hand.

- Finds locations in the perimeter of a point using a *box*. One could do this with a circle to get more accurate results, but this is only meant to be an approximation to begin with.
- Ignores the fact that the world is not flat. My application was only meant for a local region, a few 100 kilometers across. And the search perimeter only spans a few kilometers across. Making the world flat is good enough for the purpose. (Todo: A better approximation for the ratio lat/lon depending on the geolocation might help.)
- Operates with geocodes like you get from Google maps.
- Works with standard PostgreSQL **without extension** (no PostGis required), tested on PostgreSQL 9.1 and 9.2.

Without index, one would have to calculate the distance for every row in the base table and filter the closest ones. Extremely expensive with big tables.

**Edit:**
I rechecked and the current implementation allows a GisT index on points (Postgres 9.1 or later). Simplified the code accordingly.

<strike>The **major trick** is to use a functional **GiST index of *boxes***, even though the column is just a point. This makes it possible to use the existing [GiST implementation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/gist.html).</strike>

With such a (very fast) search, we can get all locations inside a box. The remaining problem: we know the number of rows, but we do not know the size of the box they are in. That's like knowing part of the answer, but not the question.

I use a similar **reverse-lookup** approach to the one described in more detail in [this related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query/22500#22500). (Only, I am not using partial indexes here - might actually work, too).

Iterate through an array of pre-defined search-steps, from very small up to "just big enough to hold at least enough locations".  Means we have to run a couple of (very fast) queries to get to the size for the search box.

Then search the base table with this box and calculate actual distance for only the few rows returned from the index. There will usually be some surplus since we found the box holding *at least* enough locations. By taking the closest ones, we effectively round the corners of the box. You could force this effect by making the box a notch bigger (multiply `radius` in the function by sqrt(2) to get completely *accurate* results, but I wouldn't go all out, since this is approximating to begin with).

This would be even faster and simpler with an [SP GiST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/spgist.html) index, available in the latest version of PostgreSQL. But I don't know if that's possible yet. We'd need an actual implementation for the data type and I didn't have the time to dive into it. If you find a way, promise to report back!

Given this simplified table with some example values (`adr` .. address):

```
CREATE TABLE adr(adr_id int, adr text, geocode point);
INSERT INTO adr (adr_id, adr, geocode) VALUES
    (1,  'adr1', '(48.20117,16.294)'),
    (2,  'adr2', '(48.19834,16.302)'),
    (3,  'adr3', '(48.19755,16.299)'),
    (4,  'adr4', '(48.19727,16.303)'),
    (5,  'adr5', '(48.19796,16.304)'),
    (6,  'adr6', '(48.19791,16.302)'),
    (7,  'adr7', '(48.19813,16.304)'),
    (8,  'adr8', '(48.19735,16.299)'),
    (9,  'adr9', '(48.19746,16.297)');
```

The index looks like this:

```
CREATE INDEX adr_geocode_gist_idx ON adr USING gist (geocode);
```

[**-> SQLfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/08d06/1)

You'll have to adjust the home area, the steps and the scaling factor to your needs. As long as you search in boxes of a few kilometers around a point, a flat earth is a good enough approximation.

You need to understand plpgsql well to work with this. I feel I have done quite enough here.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_find_around(_lat double precision, _lon double precision, _limit bigint = 50)
  RETURNS TABLE(adr_id int, adr text, distance int) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _homearea   CONSTANT box := '(49.05,17.15),(46.35,9.45)'::box;      -- box around legal area
-- 100m = 0.0008892                   250m, 340m, 450m, 700m,1000m,1500m,2000m,3000m,4500m,7000m
   _steps      CONSTANT real[] := '{0.0022,0.003,0.004,0.006,0.009,0.013,0.018,0.027,0.040,0.062}';  -- find optimum _steps by experimenting
   geo2m       CONSTANT integer := 73500;                              -- ratio geocode(lon) to meter (found by trial & error with google maps)
   lat2lon     CONSTANT real := 1.53;                                  -- ratio lon/lat (lat is worth more; found by trial & error with google maps in (Vienna)
   _radius     real;                                                   -- final search radius
   _area       box;                                                    -- box to search in
   _count      bigint := 0;                                            -- count rows
   _point      point := point($1,$2);                                  -- center of search
   _scalepoint point := point($1 * lat2lon, $2);                       -- lat scaled to adjust
BEGIN

 -- Optimize _radius
IF (_point <@ _homearea) THEN
   FOREACH _radius IN ARRAY _steps LOOP
      SELECT INTO _count  count(*) FROM adr a
      WHERE  a.geocode <@ box(point($1 - _radius, $2 - _radius * lat2lon)
                            , point($1 + _radius, $2 + _radius * lat2lon));

      EXIT WHEN _count >= _limit;
   END LOOP;
END IF;

IF _count = 0 THEN                                                     -- nothing found or not in legal area
   EXIT;
ELSE
   IF _radius IS NULL THEN
      _radius := _steps[array_upper(_steps,1)];                        --  max. _radius
   END IF;
   _area := box(point($1 - _radius, $2 - _radius * lat2lon)
              , point($1 + _radius, $2 + _radius * lat2lon));
END IF;

RETURN QUERY
SELECT a.adr_id
      ,a.adr
      ,((point (a.geocode[0] * lat2lon, a.geocode[1]) <-> _scalepoint) * geo2m)::int4 AS distance
FROM   adr a
WHERE  a.geocode <@ _area
ORDER  BY distance, a.adr, a.adr_id
LIMIT  _limit;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_find_around (48.2, 16.3, 20);
```

Returns a list of `$3` locations, if there are enough in the defined maximum search area.
Sorted by actual distance.

#### Further improvements

Build a function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_geo2m(double precision, double precision)
  RETURNS point AS
$BODY$
SELECT point($1 * 111200, $2 * 111400 * cos(radians($1)));
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION f_geo2m(double precision, double precision)
IS 'Project geocode to approximate metric coordinates.
    SELECT f_geo2m(48.20872, 16.37263)  --';
```

The (literally) global constants `111200` and `111400` are optimized for my area (Austria) from the [Length of a degree of longitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude#Length_of_a_degree_of_longitude) and [The length of a degree of latitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#The_length_of_a_degree_of_latitude), but basically just work all over the world.

Use it to add a scaled geocode to the base table, ideally a *generated column* like outlined in this answer:
[How do you do date math that ignores the year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169410/how-do-you-do-date-math-that-ignores-the-year/15179731#15179731)
Refer to **3. Black magic version** where I walk you through the process.
Then you can simplify the function some more: Scale input values once and remove redundant calculations.

Comment: Badass. This far surpasses my SQL chops. +1

Comment: @MattBall It far surpasses mine too. This is probably the more correct solution but I am going to attempt PostGIS because I have no idea how to modify this for my app.

Comment: @eliot: As I wrote: you need to know your plpgsql for this. It also doesn't hurt to understand how the earth is shaped and how coordinates work exactly. If in doubt, PostGis is the right choice to do this properly. My solution *does* work. I am running variations of this in a couple of geo-apps very effectively.

Comment: I don't doubt that this solution works. And the fact that you created a working example in sqlfiddle, I wish I could give you a few more upvotes. This makes me wish I wasn't on such a tight time schedule and could learn plpgsql. Thanks so much for this response.

Comment: @eliot: You're welcome. :) Led to a couple of improvements to my own existing code.