# Query on a time range ignoring the date of timestamps

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to query a purchases table in my rails database (Postgres) and I want to query on time ranges.

For example, I'd like to know how many purchases were made between 2 PM and 3 PM across all dates.

There is a `created_at` column in this table but I don't see how to accomplish this without searching for a specific date as well.

I've tried:

`Purchases.where("created_at BETWEEN ? and ?", Time.now - 1.hour, Time.now)`

But this ultimately will just search for today's date with those times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to extract just the hour portion from created_at using [PostgreSQL's date_part/extract function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 20
```

For example, something like this:

```
Purchases.where(["EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?", 13, 14])
```

Comment: +1 good answer, another thing to consider is timezone. User's might expect the answer to correspond to their own timezone.

Answer (score 4):

Use a simple cast to `time`:

```ruby
Purchases.where("created_at::time >= ?
             AND created_at::time <  ?", Time.now - 1.hour, Time.now)
```

This way you can easily test against *arbitrary times*.

Consider:

- Which border to include / exclude. Common practice is to *include* the lower border and *exclude* the upper. `BETWEEN` *includes* both.
- The exact data type (`timestamp` or `timestamp with time zone`) and how that interacts with your local time zone:

  - [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

#### Index

If you run these queries a lot and need them fast and your table isn't very small, you will want to create a [**functional index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) for performance:

```sql
CREATE INDEX tbl_created_at_time_idx ON tbl (cast(created_at AS time));
```

I used the [standard SQL syntax `cast()` instead of the Postgres syntactical shortcut `::`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS). This is required for indices.

This index works for a [`timestamp [without time zone]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) since the cast is `IMMUTABLE` as required for an index. But it does not work for a [`timestamp with time zone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), for the same reasons. You can fix this, but you need to define what you need exactly. Use the [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) construct to define the time zone to extract the time for. For instance, to measure against UTC time:

```sql
CREATE INDEX tbl_created_at_time_idx2
ON tbl(cast(created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS time));
```

Similar question dealing with dates ignoring the year:

- [How do you do date math that ignores the year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169410/how-do-you-do-date-math-that-ignores-the-year/15179731#15179731)