# Create timestamp index from JSON on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table on PostgreSQL with a field named `data` that is `jsonb` with a lot of objects, I want to make an index to speed up the queries. I'm using few rows to test the data (just 15 rows) but I don't want to have problems with the queries in the future. I'm getting data from the Twitter API, so with a week I get around 10gb of data. 
 If I make the normal index

`CREATE INDEX ON tweet((data->>'created_at'));`

I get a text index, if I make:

`Create index on tweet((CAST(data->>'created_at' AS timestamp)));`

I get

`ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`

I've tried to make it "inmutable" setting the timezone with

`date_trunc('seconds', CAST(data->>'created_at' AS timestamp) at time zone 'GMT')`

but I'm still getting the "immutable" error. So, How can I accomplish a timestamp index from a JSON? I know that I could make a simple column with the date because probably it will remain constant in the time, but I want to learn how to do that.

Comment: The only workaround is to create your own function that does the casting (using the time zone), declare that function as immutable and then use *that* function for the index.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This expression won't be allowed in the index either:

```
(CAST(data->>'created_at' AS timestamp) at time zone 'UTC')
```

It's not immutable, because the first cast depends on your [`DateStyle`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting (among other things). Doesn't help to translate the result to UTC *after* the function call, uncertainty has already crept in ...

The **solution** is a function that *makes* the cast immutable by fixing the time zone (like [@a_horse already hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757374/create-timestamp-index-from-json-on-postgresql#comment47648833_29757374)).

I suggest to use [`to_timestamp()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) (which is also only `STABLE`, not `IMMUTABLE`) instead of the cast to rule out some source of trouble - `DateStyle` being one.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_cast_isots(text)
  RETURNS timestamptz AS
$$SELECT to_timestamp($1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')$$  -- adapt to your needs
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Note that this returns `timestamptz`. Then:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON t (f_cast_isots(data->>'created_at'));
```

Detailed explanation for this technique in this related answer:

- [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

Related:

- [Query on a time range ignoring the date of timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368205/query-on-a-time-range-ignoring-the-date-of-timestamps/19368998#19368998)

Comment: SO should automatically float Erwin's answers to the top on any question with the postgresql tag