# Is it possible to create timestamp index in jsonb postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to create effective index on jsonb column to timestamp value in postgresql?

I tried this advice [Create timestamp index from JSON on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757374/create-timestamp-index-from-json-on-postgresql#comment47648833_29757374) but ORDER and SIMPLE WHERE operations are still using seq scan without index.

And query execution time with an index and without index no difference:

```
SELECT * FROM bums.mytable_no_ind ORDER BY (ts->>'date')::TIMESTAMP DESC
```

and

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM bums.mytable_no_ind WHERE (ts->>'date')::TIMESTAMP = NOW()
```

Information about table:

```
    create table bums.mytable_no_ind (
    s serial primary key,
    ts jsonb,
    x int,
    y int,
    z int
);
insert into bums.mytable_no_ind (ts, x, y, z) 
select 
    ('{"date": "' || clock_timestamp() || '"}')::jsonb,
    500 * RANDOM(),
    500 * RANDOM(),
    500 * RANDOM()
from generate_series(1, 1000000)
;
```

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, my question is not about slow query. I asked about possible timestamp index in jsonb columns

Comment: Well the answer you linked to clearly shows a way to create such an index. The part "*query execution time no difference*" indicates that you _are_ concerned about the performance. What exactly **is** your question then?

Comment: You should read carefully the linked answer, because it states clearly why the cast-ing to `timestamp` cannot be indexed.

Comment: I tried to create index from answer in linked question. But this index not usage in query. In query plain seq scan still usage. But I expected my index usage. And i asked - why index is not used in the queries in my post?

Comment: I found the problem. I just change (ts->>'date')::TIMESTAMP to f_cast_isots(ts->>'date') and index is work!