# Concat year and month but with a fixed size

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, datetime

I have the following dataset:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    the_debt_id varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_due date NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_paid timestamp NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('LMUS01', '2020-08-02', '2020-05-18 11:07:01'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2020-07-02', '2020-05-18 11:07:01'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2020-06-02', '2020-05-18 11:07:01'), 
       ('LMUS01', '2020-05-02', '2020-04-28 02:28:41'),
       ('LMUS01', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-01 06:29:53'),
       ('LMUS01', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-02 07:30:59'),   
       ('LMUS01', '2020-02-02', '2020-01-31 06:58:18');
```

I just wanted to concat the year and month of `the_debt_due` but when I try this:

```sql
SELECT the_debt_id, 
cast(concat(extract('year' from the_debt_due),extract('month' from the_debt_due)) as integer) 
FROM my_table
```

It returns five digits for months from January to September (like `20205` for May), and six digits for the rest of the year (like `202012` for December). Is it possible to get six digits? This is the expected output:

```
the_debt_id    concat     
LMUS01         202008
LMUS01         202007
LMUS01         202006
LMUS01         202005
LMUS01         202004
LMUS01         202003
LMUS01         202002
```

Comment: Do you need a *string* (for display)? Or a *number* (to do computations)? `extract()`, like you have it, returns type `double precision`, `concat()` force-converts it to `text` and, finally, you cast to `integer` ...

Comment: Hello @ErwinBrandstetter, I need an integer for math computations. I see that you have already answered, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For display, use `to_char()` like GMB provided.

If you need an `integer`, like your cast suggests, this is faster than casting the result of `to_char()`:

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(year FROM the_debt_due) * 100 + EXTRACT(month FROM the_debt_due))::int;
```

I tested both when optimizing for this related answer:

- [How do you do date math that ignores the year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169410/how-do-you-do-date-math-that-ignores-the-year/15179731#15179731)

Comment: Just what I needed, an integer! Thank you @Erwin Brandsetter!

Answer (score 2):

No need for padding logic. Just use `to_char()`:

```
select the_debt_id, to_char(the_debt_due, 'yyyymm') the_debt_due_char
from mytable
```