# How to make a group query to select multiple rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have a DateTime column (timestamp 2022-05-22 10:10:12) with a batch of stamps per each day.

I need to filter the rows where stamp is before 9am (here is no problem) and I'm using this code:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets
  WHERE date_part('hour'::text, tickets.date_in) < 9::double precision;
```

The output is the list of the rows where the time in timestamp is less than 9 am (50 rows from 2000).

```
date_in
2022-05-22 08:10:12
2022-04-23 07:11:13
2022-06-15 08:45:26
```

Then I need to find all the days where at least one row has a stamp before 9 am - and here I'm stuck. Any idea **how to select all the days where at least one stamp was before 9 am**?

The code I'm trying:

```sql
SELECT * into temp1 FROM tickets
WHERE date_part('hour'::text, tickets.date_in) < 9::double precision
ORDER BY date_part('day'::text, date_in);

Select * into temp2
from tickets, temp1
where date_part('day'::text, tickets.date_in) = date_part('day'::text, temp1.date_in);

Update temp2 set distorted_route = 1;
```

But this is giving me nothing.

Expected output is to get all the days where at least one route was done before 9am:

```
date_in
2022-05-22 08:10:12
2022-05-22 10:11:45
2022-05-22 12:14:59
2022-04-23 07:11:13
2022-04-23 11:42:25
2022-06-15 08:45:26
2022-06-15 15:10:57
```

Should I make an additional table (*temp1*) to feed it with the first query result (just the rows before 9am) and then make a cross table query to find in the source table *public.tickets* all the days which are equal to the *public.temp1*?

```
Select * from tickets, temp1
where TO_Char(tickets.date_in, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    = TO_Char(temp1.date_in, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

or like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tickets
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT date_in FROM TO_Char(tickets.date_in, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_Char(temp1.date_in, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
   );
```

Ideally, I'd want to avoid using a temporary table and make a request just for one table.
After that, I need to create a view or update and add some remarks to the source table.

Comment: Probably a case for `exists`; suggesting an answer though would really need details of the table schema and sample data.

Comment: I did my best to explain the issue and the goal. I hope somebody can help me to solve it..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean:

*How to select all rows where at least one row exists with a timestamp before 9 am of the same day?*

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tickets t
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tickets t1
   WHERE  t1.date_in::date = t.date_in::date  -- same day
   AND    t1.date_in::time < time '9:00'      -- time before 9:00
   AND    t1.id <> t.id                       -- exclude self
   )
ORDER  BY date_id;  -- optional, but typically helpful
```

`id` being the PK column of your undisclosed table.

But be aware that ...

1. ... typically you'll want to work with `timestamptz` instead of `timestamp`. See:

   - [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)
   - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29
2. ... this query is slow for big tables, because it cannot use a plain index on `(date_id)` (not "sargable"). Related:

   - [How do you do date math that ignores the year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169410/how-do-you-do-date-math-that-ignores-the-year/15179731#15179731)

   There are various ways to optimize performance. The best way depends on undisclosed [information for performance questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Comment: This query is very helpful! Thanks
Maybe you can give me a hint on how to get the time stored in 24h in exactly 24h by this query? 
As it is counted 15:00 like 3:00 and 3:00 is less than 9:00 so it let this path true..
Only one thing is working for me, but I'm not sure what is the issue..
date_part('hour'::text, tickets.date_in) < 9::double precision

Comment: @Houston: Postgres does not do the culturally motivated 15:00 = 3:00 thing internally. timestamps (and times) are stored as integer quantities with microsecond resolution. So use `time '9:00'` or `time '21:00'` (whichever you really mean), no ambiguity left. (Use ISO date and time syntax *everywhere* to avoid problems.)

Comment: The problem is that I have in output batch of the times like from 6:00 till the 15:00
I tried to call just the time from the column - and it is giving an output in 24h (15:00), but when I'm using some argument (like for the **row where 15:00**) `t1.date_in::time < time '9:00' ` - **it lets to path this row**. Have no glue where to dig..

Comment: @Houston: Please ask your new question as new question with the necessary details to make it clear. There will be a simple solution.