# How to store mmyy in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, date-arithmetic

There are two variables:

```
$mm = "01";
$yy = "22";
```

I need to store it in one column Postges `mmyy`.
What is type `mmyy` must be if there is not day?
Or I can use the first day of month always like: `010122`.

Eventually, I want to filter rows with `where mmyy > now()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat it like a date/time value, preferably store it as **`date`**. That would be:

```
date '2022-01-01'
```

Occupies only 4 bytes, same as `int4`.
Always use ISO format, which is unambiguous regardless of your locale settings. [More in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)

To convert your variables, you might use the Postgres function [`to_date()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE):

```sql
test=> SELECT to_date('2201', 'YYMM');
  to_date   
------------
 2022-01-01
(1 row)

test=> SELECT to_date('22'::text || '01'::text, 'YYMM');
  to_date   
------------
 2022-01-01
(1 row)
```

Or prepare a date literal in ISO format.

When compared to `now()` (which returns `timestamp with time zone`) the `date` value is coerced to the first instant of Jan 1st, 2022 at the time zone determined by the current setting of your session. See:

- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684)

So it works as intended out of the box - except that you possibly haven't thought about time zones, yet ...

---

For other tasks with date arithmetic, an integer might be a good choice. See:

- [How do you do date math that ignores the year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169410/how-do-you-do-date-math-that-ignores-the-year/15179731#15179731)

Comment: Thank you, so before add to table I have to prepare $mm and $yy to date format?

Comment: @Dmitro: Yes, there are simple and safe ways with `to_date()`. I added pointers.